# get_json_object() - parsing a json string in Impala - Unable to parse the key starting with a number

Tags: sql, json, hive, impala, hue

I am working on a big table(mytable), where in I have to parse a column of type string. The column(value) is a json string as shown below.
mytable -->

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bgtn | {"3Dtyu":"4gg","3tyi":34.98,"rty_amt":45.99,"4ftyh":"5AA"} |

I have tried the below mentioned query in Impala (Hue)

```
select get_json_object(value,"$.3Dtyu") as value
from mytable
where id=1;
```

Error msg :

> errorMessage="UDF ERROR: Failed to parse json path '$.3Dtyu': Expected key at position 2\n"

I have also tried few things:

1. Code 1

```
select get_json_object(value,"$.*") as value
from mytable
where id=1;
```

Output :

| value |
| --- |
| ["4gg",34.98,45.99,"5AA"] |

2. Code 2

```
select get_json_object(value,"$.rty_amt") as value
from mytable
where id=1;
```

Output :

| value |
| --- |
| [45.99] |

But when parsing the particular key inside which starts with a digit, `get_json_object` fails.
I will really appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you need to update your database engine: https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/IMPALA-8547

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert to MAP: remove curly brackets and double-quotes, then use str_to_map function.

Demo:

```
select mymap['3Dtyu'] as `3Dtyu`,
       mymap['3tyi'] as `3tyi`
from
(
select str_to_map(regexp_replace('{"3Dtyu":"4gg","3tyi":34.98,"rty_amt":45.99,"4ftyh":"5AA"}', '\\{|\\}|"','')) as mymap
)s
```

Result:

```
 3dtyu       3tyi
  
  4gg        34.98
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error for the demo you have provided. The error : ParseException: Syntax error in line 7:undefined: select mymap['3Dtyu'] as `3Dtyu`, ^ Encountered: [ Expected: AND, AS, BETWEEN, DEFAULT, DIV, FROM, ILIKE, IN, IREGEXP, IS, LIKE, LIMIT, NOT, OR, ORDER, REGEXP, RLIKE, UNION, COMMA, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: @AnukritiSingh I tested it on Hive. Unfortunately I do not have Impala to test it. Try to name columns differently.